# Which sugar is used in pastry more often, white or brown?

Tags: flavor, sugar, pastry, brown-sugar

Which sugar is used in pastry more often, white or brown? Which sugar provides more taste/flavor?

Comment: Hi, Rashk!  It's not completely clear what you're asking from your question.  Do you have some specific pastry you're trying to make?

Comment: Hello! It seems you are asking two questions in one, one about the frequency of use, the other about flavor. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use both white or brown sugar.

brown sugar are naturally moist,so when you use brown sugar in the pastry so your pastry become more softer and moisture.

and brown sugar contain more mineral than refined white sugar and brown sugar gives you mineral,calcium,iron and potassium.

so in most cases brown sugar is added in pastry and it gives more taste.

and when i made pastries or such like baking things means cake etc i prefer brown sugar because of its benefits and also for the taste.

so i too recommened you brown sugar in pastry

i hope it helps.....

Comment: i disagree with this. the overwhelming majority of pastries use white sugar. whether this is a good thing or not is a matter of opinion

Comment: It may be the case that in different countries and cooking cultures the relative prevalence of white and brown sugar in pastry differs. Aaisha and canardgras may both be correct in their own culinary environments.

Answer (score 3):

For a short answer, I recommend using brown sugar in your case.

Brown sugar has more of it's own flavour, while white sugar is very plain, so when you ask "which one give more taste", you probably want brown. Brown sugar tastes this way because it contains molasses (a juice from the sugarcane).

An alternative to brown cane sugar is "raw sugar" (also known as "natural brown sugar", "whole sugar", or "unrefined sugar"). There are also similar sugars not made with sugarcane, such as maple sugar and coconut sugar.

There may be cases where you don't want the molasses to interfere with the other flavours (such as chocolate). You can use white sugar, while golden sugar (or light brown sugar) is in-between. However, I personally prefer brown sugar in most pastries. It works very well with cinnamon, apples, and raisins. You can also add additional molasses if you want the brown sugar to taste *stronger*.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is a nice answer! Please note that we don’t discuss general “health” and “nutrition”. It’s perfectly ok to say that something contains more of this or that substance, but I strongly recommend to not make claims that something is “healthier”. You can always [edit] your post accordingly. As for all new users we recommend the [tour] and our [help] to learn more about how the site works. Again, welcome!

Comment: I am removing all vague health and nutrition bits from this post. If you want to add factual information back in, use the [edit] function.